# Why is my WordPress WP-Store Locator not showing nearby stores when I click 'Use My Location' on Instagram mobile?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, store, geolocator

For mobile version am facing issue regarding Instagram (links) and (store locator) plugin in WordPress
I am expecting that if click on Use My Location it should be show all stores which are near for me.
When someone is clicking on my website link which is defined in my Instagram's info, it is redirect successfully on WordPress Website but clicking on Use My Location (button) it is showing all stores from Florida but my location is not Florida. This action perform well in Desktop and Tablet Version.

Website Link : https://slices4you.com/

Instagram Link : https://www.instagram.com/slices4youdeals

[Use My Location Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYA4d.jpg)

[Instagram info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsrgR.png)

I am expecting that if i click on Use My Location it should be show all stores which are near for me.